# Is there a way to guess a shared server's control panel's version?

Tags: web-hosting, fingerprinting, shared-hosting

I am performing research on the security of control panel software for shared hosting providers, and I am interested to know if there is a way to identify the version of the control panel software that the server is using, for instance, cPanel, Plesk, or DirectAdmin, by having server IP and a website that is hosted on that server?

Comment: When you say that you have a website hosted on the server, does that imply that you have access to the control planel?

Comment: No I do not. I just have a mapping between websites and their corresponding IP address

Comment: Try a bunch of exploits - usually if it's one of those crappy panels it will fall pretty quickly. Otherwise you may be facing a competent sysadmin and there is no panel.

Answer (score 1):

**Kinda.**
There is no format of displaying version number that all control panels use and so each control panel displays the version their own unique way.

If you want to find the version for a specific control panel I suggest you do the following:

- Try looking the source code, the corners of the UI, headers in the requests or even google "How to find out what version X is running?" and see if there is anything relevant there.
- Look for unique actions of the control panel and compare it to the versions update log (Assuming there is one on the control panel website) to find similar actions.
- Set up a script that is able to identify a version of a control panel based on unique identifiers per each version and run it to check a specific site.